# Apply Filters To MySql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, database

Am Writing my own SQL Query to Fetch Data From Two Different Models and also i have some filters , since i was using Spatie Query Builder i just configure my filters in allowedFilters() method and everything is okay , but know am moving from Spatie to Raw Sql Query where i can manipulate each character of my query giving below 2 examples one using Spatie Query Builder and another using my Custom Query the question here is how to apply those filters into my SQL Query when they sent in the request

**Spatie Example **

```
$transactions = QueryBuilder::for(Transaction::class)
                        ->with(['payable' => function (MorphTo $morphTo) {
                            $morphTo->morphWith([
                                Reservation::class => ['unit', 'depositInsuranceTransactions' , 'withdrawInsuranceTransactions', 'creator', 'customer', 'customer.nationality', 'customer.highlight'],
                            ]);
                        }])
                        ->with(['wallet','creator','last_user_update'])
                        ->allowedFilters([
                            AllowedFilter::scope('by_number'),
                            AllowedFilter::scope('by_reservation_number'),
                            AllowedFilter::scope('by_customer_id_number'),
                            AllowedFilter::scope('by_unit_number'),
                            AllowedFilter::scope('by_creator'),
                            AllowedFilter::scope('by_payment_type'),
                            AllowedFilter::scope('by_date_from'),
                            AllowedFilter::scope('by_date_to'),
                            AllowedFilter::scope('by_term')
                        ])
                        ->allowedSorts([
                                'id',
                                '-id',
                                'created_at',
                                '-created_at'
                        ])
                        ->whereHasMorphIn('payable', ['App\\Team','App\\Reservation'], function ($query, $modelType) use($reservations_ids,$team_id , $type){

                            if ($modelType == 'App\\Team') {
                                $query->where('payable_type' , 'App\\Team')
                                ->where('payable_id',$team_id);
                            }

                            if ($modelType === 'App\\Reservation') {
                                $query->where('payable_type' , 'App\Reservation')
                                ->with('unit', 'depositInsuranceTransactions' , 'withdrawInsuranceTransactions' ,'customer','customer.nationality','customer.highlight')
                                ->whereIntegerInRaw('payable_id', $reservations_ids);
                            }
                        })
                        ->where('amount', '!=' , 0)
                        ->where('type' , '=' , $type)
                        ->where('is_public' , 1)
                        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                        ->orderByDesc('number')
                        ->simplePaginate(20);
```

**And This is My Custom Query**

```
$transactions  =
    DB::select(
            DB::raw("SELECT tr.*, w.decimal_places
                    FROM transactions tr
                        JOIN wallets w ON w.id = tr.wallet_id
                    where
                    (
                    -- I Wanna Put Here Some Conditions When the filter x is not null apply it to the query
                    )
                    AND (
                            (
                                tr.payable_type = :team_base_class
                                AND tr.payable_id = :team_id
                                AND tr.amount != 0
                                AND tr.type = :team_transaction_type
                                AND tr.is_public = 1
                                AND tr.deleted_at IS NULL
                            )
                            OR (
                                    tr.payable_type = :reservation_base_class
                                AND tr.payable_id IN ( $implodeded_reservations_ids 
                            )
                            AND tr.amount != 0
                            AND tr.type = :reservation_transaction_type
                            AND tr.is_public = 1
                            AND tr.deleted_at IS NULL
                        )
                    )

                    ORDER BY tr.number DESC
            ") // End of DB RAW

            , array(
                'team_base_class' => 'App\\Team',
                'reservation_base_class' => 'App\\Reservation',
                'team_id' => $team_id,
                'team_transaction_type' => $type,
                'reservation_transaction_type' => $type
            )
    ); // End of DB SELECT
```

**My Filters Coming From Request **

```
{
"by_number":"129",
"by_reservation_number":"120",
"by_date_from":"2022-02-01 12:00",
"by_date_to":"2022-02-11 12:00",
"by_payment_type":"cash",
"by_term":"36708"
}
```

I Tried So Many Times Applying IF condition inside where but always getting syntax error and i don't know if what am doing right or wrong.

**Why Am Moving To Custom Query Rather Than Spatie**

Well am looking for the most optimized performance i can get and i really found that direct SQL Queries are so fast rather than any extra tooling like spatie or even eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're trying to do doesn't seem to match the raw sql below.

As for the conditionals, if you used the query builder you could use its when method.

```php
$transactions = DB::query()
    ->select('tr.*', 'w.decimal_places')
    ->from('transactions', 'tr'
    ->join('wallets w', 'w.id', 'tr.wallet_id')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
        $query->when(isset($filters['a']), function ($query) use ($filters) { $query->where('a', $filters['a']); })
              ->when(isset($filters['b']), function ($query) use ($filters) { $query->where('b', $filters['b']); })
              ->when(isset($filters['c']), function ($query) use ($filters) { $query->where('c', $filters['c']); })
              ->when(isset($filters['d']), function ($query) use ($filters) { $query->where('d', $filters['d']); })
              ->when(isset($filters['e']), function ($query) use ($filters) { $query->where('e', $filters['e']); });
    })
    ->where(function ($query) use ($team_id, $type) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($team_id, $type) {
            $query->where('tr.payable_type', 'App\\Team')
                ->where('tr.payable_id', $team_id)
                ->where('tr.amount', '!=',  0)
                ->where('tr.type', $type)
                ->where('tr.is_public', 1)
                ->whereNull('tr.deleted')
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($reservations_ids_array, $type) {
            $query->where('tr.payable_type', 'App\\Reservation')
                ->whereIn('tr.payable_id', $reservations_ids_array)
                ->where('tr.amount', '!=', 0)
                ->where('tr.type', $type)
                ->where('tr.is_public', 1)
                ->whereNull('tr.deleted_at')
        });
    })
    ->orderByDesc('tr.number')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks man appreciate your effort actually i tested your proposed answer and it works perfect with the same performance i expect ...

Comment: But i have a question with this way i can not eager load any relation cause with() will be undefined what do you propose , shall use joins if so i have Team & Reservation with a payable relation in Transaction how can i achieve this in the select

Comment: Find a SQL query that works for you and then use the query builder to create it with those filters. Eloquent would let you use relationships. I do not know how Spatie's Query Builder works behind the scenes or the amount of data you are working with or what is data you really want to return so I can't really optimize anything.

Comment: I really understand you and for the part of filters I already managed it the way you suggested in the mean time I will stick with the laravel’s query builder and I will not use eloquent as I may have a tenant with more than 100k financial transactions so to make it clear if it was not clear in the previous comment can I join with reservations tbl and teams tbl to be able to get some info from them based on transaction payable type (App\\Reservation - App\\Team ) ?!

Comment: Hey Man , i made my joins as i mentioned in the previous comment and they do worked as i expected and want !

Comment: That's great If you are using a filter very commonly, you might get a bit more performance by creating indexes as well.

Comment: Yeah sure indexes are very important and am taking care of that point , even am using virtual columns (mysql) cause some of the filters are coming from json column and now way to index json scalar values so the virtual columns solved my issue and filtering results based on json scalar value became very fast